# How can I populate a drop down list control Collection?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, collections, drop-down-menu

How can I populate a drop down list control (ASP.NET) from a SPListTemplateCollection (SharePoint 2007) ?

```
SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;

ddlTemplateList = new DropDownList();
ddlTemplateList.DataSource = web.ListTemplates;
ddlTemplateList.DataBind();
```

This code doesn't work in a right way... The name of the list template is not showed.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify `DataTextField and DataValueField` to make it work.

```
ddlTemplateList.DataSource = web.ListTemplates;
ddlTemplateList.DataTextField = "DisplayColumnName";
ddlTemplateList.DataValueField = "ValudColumnName";
ddlTemplateList.DataBind();
```

Comment: I use your code, but when I deploy my project, an error occure on the sharepoint website.

Comment: always provide the error when possible! We cannot help you without it!

Comment: Sorry, but the message isn't very useful : "An unexpected error has occurred."

Comment: Is a there a specific value to replace "DisplayColumnName" and "ValueColumnName" ? Without ddlTemplateList.DataValueField = "ValudColumnName" and ddlTemplateList.DataTextField = "DisplayColumnName", the dropdownlist is populated with "Microsoft.Sharepoint.SPListTemplate".

Comment: Can't help ? I'm still blocked... :(

Answer (score 1):

use DisplayMember and ValueMember property!

**update**

DisplayMember and ValueMember are property for WinForm controls.

For asp.net correct solution, as metioned by Muhammad, is to use DataTextField and DataValueField.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
        List<SPWeb> lstSPWeb = web.ListTemplates
        ddlTemplateList.DataSource = lstSPWeb;
        ddlTemplateList.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (SPListTemplate lt in SPContext.Current.Web.ListTemplates)
            ddlTemplateList.Items.Add(new ListItem(lt.Name, lt.Type.ToString()));
```